# Collecting shapefiles from different users - any rules for quality data/quality control?

Tags: shapefile, data-quality

Apologies in advance for this very basic question!

My company collects market information from forestry projects in an annual survey. This year, we are trying to add a spatial element to our analysis. The current plan is to ask survey respondents to upload a shapefile of their project.

My question is: if we collect all of these shapefile responses from individual companies, will there be any difficulties in merging them into a single global map? Ex: do we need to make sure that each shapefile is set to the same projection? Or is there something else I need to check for quality control?

I don't know much about shapefiles or qGIS, so I'm worried that I might not think of a basic question to ensure quality data. Right now, I'm planning on the survey saying "Please upload a shapefile (.shp) of your forest project here". Is that okay?